# Query in MPI initialization

Tags: mpi, openmpi

If we call MPI_Init() we know that multiple copies of the same executable run on different machines. Suppose MPI_Init() is in a function f(), then will multiple copies of main() function exist too?

**The main problem that I am facing is of taking inputs**. *In effect, what is happening is that input is being taken once but the main function is running several times*. **The processor with rank 0 always seems to have the input, rest of them have random values.** So to send the values do we have to broadcast the input from processor 0 to all the other processors?

Comment: You should execute MPI_Init() only once (that is, in your source code it may occur exactly once). The parameters to your program should be readable on all processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MPI_Init() doesn't create multiple copies, it just initializes in-process MPI library. Multiple copies of your process are created *before* that, most probably with some kind of `mpirun` command (that is how you run your MPI application). All processes are independent from the beginning, so answering the first part of your question — yes, multiple copies of `main()` will exist, and they will exist even if you don't call MPI_Init.

The answer to your question about inputs depends on nature of the inputs: if it's typed in from console, then you have to input the values only in one process (e.g. rank 0) and then broadcast them. If the inputs are in some file or specified as a command-line argument, then all processes can access them.

Comment: Thanks. :) 
I had one more doubt. Suppose I have a function doSomething(int *A) where doSomething() is called by some other application and my MPI code lies within this function, so even then do we need to provide a broadcast mechanism?

Comment: If I get it right, the 'some other application' is part of the code, i.e. it is linked with your program. Then, after you start your MPI program, you have N separate processes (possibly running on different machines) each containing a copy of that 'application', and you will have N calls to doSomething - each on its machine with its local A.

Just imagine that you compiled your program and started it on 10 computers manually — processes are isolated and don't know about each other (unless they call MPI library), that's exactly what happens after mpirun.

Comment: MPI is not multi-threading. In multi-threading, you can initialize some shared variables and then spawn threads using them (maybe you would like to do the same in your program); this requires shared memory and therefore is limited to one machine. MPI doesn't have shared memory model, so programming inter-process communications becomes more difficult, but MPI applications can run on multiple machines, and this is a huge advantage.